# helm chart dependency - Error: directory charts/stable/tomcat not found

Tags: dependencies, kubernetes-helm, helm3

i've created helm chart, and trying to add dependencies to it.
I've added the dependencies section in Chart.yaml .. however when i run the 'helm dependency update' command or package command, it throws error.

From what i understand, based on the dependencies specified, helm should download the dependencies and put in 'charts' folder.

```
# create the helm chart, name - assign4
helm create assign4 -n helm


# added the dependencies section to Chart.yaml

dependencies:
- name: stable/tomcat
  version: 3.0.1
  url: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/cloudnativeapp/tomcat 


Karans-MacBook-Pro:assign4 karanalang$ helm dep build
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "ingress-nginx" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "concourse" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "bitnami" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "prometheus-community" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
Error: directory charts/stable/tomcat not found


Karans-MacBook-Pro:helm karanalang$ helm package assign4 -n helm -u
Error: directory /Users/karanalang/Documents/Technology/helm/assign4/charts/stable/tomcat not found
```

What need to be done to fix this ?
tia !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following in Charts.yaml, to fix the issue:

```
dependencies:
- name: tomcat
  version: '9.1.5'
  repository: 'https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami'
```

i.e. specified the repository and the correct version,
the name can be anything we choose.

Answer (score 0):

Artifact Hub allows you to explore Helm charts but does not store them. You should update the URL with the URL of the Helm registry itself.

Based on what I see on Artifact Hub, you should use `https://cloudnativeapp.github.io/charts/curated/` instead.

[image]

Learn more on https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_dependency/

Comment: i tried using the url you suggested, that does not work... specifying the repository works.